# Handling currency using <h:selectOneMenu> in JSF

Tags: jsf, currency, jsf-2.2

I'm using an `<h:selectOneMenu>`on the header of a template `<p:layoutUnit position="north".../>`  as follows.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{currencyRateBean.currency}" onchange="submit();">
    <f:selectItems var="row" value="#{currencyBean.currency}" itemLabel="#{row}" itemValue="#{row}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This list is populated using a `List<String>` representing a list of currencies. The list is stored in an application scoped bean, `CurrencyBean`.

The JSF managed bean involved is as follows.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public final class CurrencyRateBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String currency;
    private BigDecimal currencyRate;

    public CurrencyRateBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        currencyRate=new BigDecimal(1);
    }

    public BigDecimal getCurrencyRate() {
        return currencyRate;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        URLConnection connection;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.exchangerate-api.com/INR/"+currency+"/1?k=FQRxs-xT2tk-NExQj");
            connection = url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String jsonObject = "";
            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                jsonObject += line;
            }

            this.currencyRate = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, BigDecimal.class);
            this.currency = currency;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(in!=null){in.close();}
        }
    }
}
```

The `setCurrency()` method is invoked on changing a currency in `<h:selectOneMenu>` (`onchange="submit();"`) **which is a POST request** as it should be.

After this request is completed, there is a duplicate page submit on refreshing the page. To avoid this duplicate submit, a GET Http request should arise after this POST request is made.

How can this be made?

<sub>Please suggest, if there is a better, new, precise alternative for handling a multi-currency application.</sub>

Comment: It depends on what you really need and want. Does it need to be live currency data or data obtained with a regular interval of time (like every 1 day, 1hour, 1min, or x frequency) ? You could simply have a container managed timer that updates currency data in an application scoped bean. Then you could use that application scoped data in any other parts of your web application(s). That works great and reduces overload.

Comment: The problem is not related to currency. Live currency rate is obtained  correctly from the URL given. The problem is about a duplicate form submission (even though a duplicate submit in this case, does not perform any mulfunction, I seriously dislike it).

Comment: Get rid of the `onchange` event listener, and use `p:ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and avoid `onchange` as much as possible.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{currencyRateBean.currency}">
<p:ajax event="valueChange" update="here write the id(s) of component(s) or "@all" to rerender the whole page (which is really bad)" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"/>
<f:selectItems var="row" value="#{currencyBean.currency}" itemLabel="#{row}" itemValue="#{row}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: May I know the usage of `partialSubmit` in `<p:ajax>` here?